# Resize content to window size

Tags: html, css

I am designing a new website (for now it's far from anything) but I am struggling to resize the content inside it, to the actual window size. Pictures speak a thousand words. The first picture is the correct way of how it should be, the one below is how I've got it when I resize the window.

[image]

[image]

```
<div class="header">
<div class="hdrmast-topbar">
    <div class="container">
        <span>Test :: Link 1 | Link 2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am going to have two bars in the header section, one of them is the hdrmast-topbar present in the code. The parent will be fixed and will move with the scroll. However, I want the content to resize with the window, like here for example: http://incub.ro/

At the moment, the header is in relative position state, as I was experimenting with this matter.

```css
/* Header */

.header { min-width: 100%; position: relative; }
.hdrmast-topbar { background-color: #000; width: 100%; max-height: 25px; font-size:   11px; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; }
.hdrmast-topbar span { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

/* Global */

.container { width: 1120px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove

```
.container { width: 1120px;
```

use `width: 100%;` instead...

Comment: I want it to be 1120px. This is the content container so the website content is more in the center rather than on the edges. Unless that poses as an issue?

Comment: I don't get it. You want THAT size, AND autoresizing ?

Comment: Exactly. Sorry if I explained it wrong. Someone was a bit ignorant and went to minus the question. width: 100% works, but now the content isn't in the centre anymore :P

Comment: Is it safe to use width: 60% for example? I see it's working, but not sure what effect it will have on other classes.

Comment: This depends on your HTML / CSS, by the way you have to choose between a fixed width or a dynamic width... if you want your banner to have the same width of the content of the site, then include both in a outer div, and set 60% or whatever to that div. Using margin: auto you can keep all the site centered, i suggest you to play with settings a bit, with css you can do almost everything.

Answer (score 2):

You could give the container a max-width of 1120px, and a width of 100%.

```
​.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:blue;
    max-width:1120px;
    width:100%;
}​
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tDjA9/2/embedded/result/

Hope this helps, and that I have understood your question correct.. :-)

Edit--

To get the same effect as the website you posted, you properly want to use position:fixed instead.

I have created a new jsfiddle to show this. http://jsfiddle.net/tDjA9/6/embedded/result/ :-)

Comment: You have :) Just as you posted, I worked out a similar code, but I removed the center margin and it was a bit wonky, but it works really well now. Thank you :D

Comment: Super! :-) I added a new little example of using fixed, instead of relative, to make the bar stick when scrolling. ;-)